# Volume between two cones with intersecting axes

Tags: multivariable-calculus, euclidean-geometry, volume

I have two cones with given vertex coordinates, axis direction and aperture angle. I know that the axes of the two cones are intersecting in a point (see the figure attached), which coordinates are straightforward to find. I'd like to find the volume of the intersection (green volume in the figure).

[Two intersecting cones sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91omG.png)

I made some lit search, but I found nothing and all the approaches I am using seems to fail.
Is there a closed form or iterative method to compute that volume?
Additionally, what if the cones are more than two?

Comment: Your figure hides the fact that there are different configurations. See fig. 2,3,4,5 [here](http://www.grad.hr/geomteh3d/prodori/prodor_stst_eng.html) for example. This means that hopefully a unique theoretical answer is unreachable. If you need only an approximate value, use a MonteCarlo simulation.

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality center the first cone with aperture angle $\alpha$ at the origin and aim it along the $z$ axis. Then consider the vertex of the second cone at $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ with aperture angle $\beta$ aligned in the $\vec{n}$ direction. Then the equation for the cone is given by

$$\vec{n}\cdot(x-x_0,y-y_0,z-z_0) = |\vec{n}|\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+(z-z_0)^2}\cos\beta$$

Squaring and converting to spherical coordinates gives us

$$r^2\left(\vec{n}\cdot(\sin\theta\cos\phi-x_0,\sin\theta\sin\phi-y_0,\cos\theta-z_0)\right)^2$$

$$ = \vec{n}^2\cos^2\beta\left(r^2-2r(x_0\sin\theta\cos\phi+y_0\sin\theta\sin\phi+z_0\cos\theta)+x_0^2+y_0^2+z_0^2\right)$$

$$$$

$$ \implies r = \frac{x_0\sin\theta\cos\phi+y_0\sin\theta\sin\phi+z_0\cos\theta}{1-\left(\frac{\vec{n}\cdot(\sin\theta\cos\phi-x_0,\sin\theta\sin\phi-y_0,\cos\theta-z_0)}{|\vec{n}|\cos\beta}\right)^2}$$
$$\pm \sqrt{\left(\frac{x_0\sin\theta\cos\phi+y_0\sin\theta\sin\phi+z_0\cos\theta}{1-\left(\frac{\vec{n}\cdot(\sin\theta\cos\phi-x_0,\sin\theta\sin\phi-y_0,\cos\theta-z_0)}{|\vec{n}|\cos\beta}\right)^2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{x_0^2+y_0^2+z_0^2}{1-\left(\frac{\vec{n}\cdot(\sin\theta\cos\phi-x_0,\sin\theta\sin\phi-y_0,\cos\theta-z_0)}{|\vec{n}|\cos\beta}\right)^2}\right)}$$

$$\equiv f(\theta,\phi)\pm h(\theta,\phi)$$

Then the volume is "simply"

$$V = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\alpha\int_{f-h}^{f+h}r^2\sin\theta\:dr\:d\theta \:d\phi$$

Comment: IMHO (I may be wrong), this cannot cover the different possible kinds of boundaries one can have (see fig. 2 to 5 of this [document](http://www.grad.hr/geomteh3d/prodori/prodor_stst_eng.html) I had already mentionned above)

Comment: @JeanMarie it doesn't seem like it should matter. The boundary/intersection type doesn't look like it ever changes the fact that there are two surfaces in the radial direction (with the exception of the common tangent plane case but I am ignoring that one since that integral is infinite anyway). Since the cones are described with apertures angles that would also mean they are all circular so those elliptical cases go away, too. I see your point about the "opposite facing" cones though.

Comment: I think that the different cases will appear when choosing the effective $\pm$ sign to place in front of the big  square root, that may change for a same configuration $+$ for a certain part and $-$ for another one of the domain...

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thank you for your reply. It is very interesting. However, I do not get how in the second step (after converting to spherical coordinates) you can collect $r^2$ in the LHS, since $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ do not depend on $r$.